# Angular 2 - Can't find module angular/core

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I'm coming here and asking a question that has been already answered in another post, but all the solutions don't work. So, I'm creating a new angular2 app from the quickstart folder of angular website.

I've done `npm install` and all is okay, I have my node_modules folder at the root.

But, when I'm doing `ng serve`, this is the error I got :

```
ERROR in angular/src/app/app.component.ts (1,27): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ERROR in angular/src/app/app.component.ts (8,14): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
ERROR in angular/src/app/app.module.ts (1,31): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
ERROR in angular/src/app/app.module.ts (2,26): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ERROR in angular/src/app/app.module.ts (16,14): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
ERROR in angular/src/main.ts (1,32): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
ERROR in angular/src/main.ts (2,40): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
```

This is my folder structure :

[image]

And this is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Edit :**

This is my `app.module.ts` :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: app.module.ts content also please

Comment: I've just edited

Comment: check inside /node_module, do you have @angular/core ?

Comment: Yep, I've all the folders it tell me it can't find

Comment: You may need to upgrade your packages

Comment: Check if your `npm` is appropriately set. for instance is it global or locally installed.

Comment: Are you using windows? At first glance everything looks correct to me. I have had nothing but problems using npm and angular-cli on Windows though. It seems like something breaks with each angular-cli update and I end up just nuking the entire thing and reinstalling it, globally and locally, every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through my tsconfig.json file and found that your tsconfig.json differs from mine. The "include" & "exclude" key values pairs are different. Have a look.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my tsconfig. maybe it helps:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```